# Replace green background to transparent background in video using FFMPEG Chroma key feature

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg

I need to replace the green background color to transparent background in the video. I have used FFMPEG Chroma key feature but it replaced green color with black background.

I used below commands:

```
    val outputVideoPath = FileUtil.createMediaFilePathforChroma(this@ChromaActivity, 1)
        cmdList.append("ffmpeg").append("-y")
        cmdList.append("-i").append(
            getFilePath(
                checkUrl(
                    getSilentAudioFilePath(
                        R.raw.transparent, "transparent.mp4"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        cmdList.append("-i").append(reducedFrameRatePath)
        cmdList.append("-filter_complex")
        cmdList.append("[1:v]scale=$width:$height,chromakey=0x00FF00:similarity=.455[ckout];[0:v]scale=$width:$height[out0];[out0][ckout]overlay[out]")
        cmdList.append("-map").append("[out]")
        cmdList.append("-t").append(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(videodata?.endduration!!).toString())
        cmdList.append("-preset").append("ultrafast")
        cmdList.append("-c:a").append("copy")
        cmdList.append("-c:v").append("libx264")
        cmdList.append("-pix_fmt").append("yuva420p")
        cmdList.append("-metadata:s:v:0")
        cmdList.append("alpha_mode=0")
        cmdList.append(outputVideoPath)
```

I have also checked with alpha_mode = 1.

Output video format is mp4.

So, I want the resulted video with transparent background instead of black background.

Answer (score 0):

Output by MP4 defaults to the H.264 codec for the video. H.264 does not support alpha.

> You can output to .mov with a video codec -c:v of png or qtrle. There
> are others but they have restrictions on resolution and framerate.
>
> You can't use the overlay filter as it doesn't output to a pixel
> format with alpha. So, just the chromakey filter, and no color source.

Comment: What will be the final command?

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "chromakey=0x70de77:0.1:0.2" -c copy -c:v png output.mov

Comment: The resulted video shows file not found or unsupported file type.